# when using Vue methods I cannot use "this" when accessing data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

here's my code:

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        groups: [],
    },

    methods: {
        loadGroups(){
            axios.get('/api/groups')
                .then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    app.groups = response.data; //The important line
                });
        },
        addGroup(){
            this.loadGroups();
            console.log(1);
        }
    },
```

In `loadGroups` method I'm using `app.groups = response.data;` and it works fine but I would rather use `this.groups = response.data;` or something like that, but I cannot do that as `this` refers to window, not Vue instance. How can I do that to look more friendly?

Comment: Call `.bind(this)` after callback or make it an arrow function

Comment: Have you tried using `data: { return {  } }` with `this.groups`? Ref: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's three approaches, with most modern going first:

```
loadGroups(){
    axios.get('/api/groups')
        .then(response => {   // for arrow functions `this` is just another variable
            // handle success
            this.groups = response.data;
        });
}

loadGroups(){
    axios.get('/api/groups')
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            this.groups = response.data;
        }.bind(this));     // binding `this` to the function makes it keep `this`
}

loadGroups(){
    var that = this;        // old style approach with a proxy variable
    axios.get('/api/groups')
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            that.groups = response.data;
        });
}
```

The reason your `this` is getting lost is that the callback is not called as a method. A method call happens when the function is defined with `function` keyword (not an arrow) and you call it from a property on an object (i.e. there is a dot somewhere - or at least square brackets). The object is called "receiver", and is assigned to `this`.

```
const obj = {
  not_method: x => x * 2,
  method: function(x) { return x*2; }
}
obj.not_method()    // not a method call (arrow); `this` is unaffected
f = obj.method; f() // not a method call (not property); `this` is `global` or `window`
obj.method()        // method call; `this` is `obj`
obj['method']()     // still a method call; `this` is obj
```

`axios.get` doesn't care about `this`; it receives a parameter, e.g. as `callback`, and calls it: `callback(response)`; as there's no dots or square brackets in `callback`, it's not a method call, and `this` is the global scope.

The first piece of code changes the function into an arrow function. Arrow functions, by their definition, completely ignore `this`, treating it as any other variable. Thus, `this` will be closed over by the function, and you can access it from the closure for the value it had outside the closure.

The second piece of code uses `Function.prototype.bind` to force a function to assign `this` to a value of our choosing. It can also fill some of the parameters, but we are not using it for that, just the receiver.

The third piece of code simulates the first one, before arrow functions were a thing. We assign the value of `this` to another variable, which is not magic like `this`, and will thus be captured in the closure by the normal mechanism.

Comment: I see, now, I've been using regular function instead of a method, that makes sense, thank you!